# iOS giving an object stats without having data in code

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an iOS game where I have a player which has different stats depending on it's name. I am currently simply putting it in my code:

```
switch name {
case "chicken":
    player.size = 20
    player.weight = 5
    ...
```

However, it doesn't feel right to put data in the code and it's much work if I have to do this for about 25 different players. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You can use an external database for this, but I don't really see the problem with this approach if there are really just 25 players. Just make sure you store it in a separate model file and you will be fine.

Comment: What are you using this information for, displaying it in the UI or using it in code elsewhere to calculate something? In any case, where else would you think it could be put? In a file? Directly on the UI? I don't see how any of these would make your life easier. You have to write down this information at least once regardless of where you store it. If you store it in code you can reference to it anywhere else from code, display it on UI or store it in a file and you only need to change it at once place if you decide to change it later on.

Comment: I'm using it to calculate something. I thought there maybe was an cleaner way to handle this, but if it's okay, then I will stick with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have stated in the comments, you can just store this data in your code. You may wish to make use of a `protocol` though. Below is just something quick I put together in a Swift Playground that you can use as a reference.

```
import UIKit

protocol PlayerProtocol {
    var name: String { get }
    var size: Int { get }
    var weight: Int { get }
}

struct Chicken: PlayerProtocol {
    var name: String = "Chicken"
    var size: Int = 20
    var weight: Int = 5
}

struct Turkey: PlayerProtocol {
    var name: String = "Turkey"
    var size: Int = 30
    var weight: Int = 10
}

class MyClass {
    func myFunc(player: PlayerProtocol) {
        print(player.size)
    }
}

MyClass().myFunc(player: Chicken())  // prints "20"
```

You can do some reading up on protocols here:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/148448/introducing-protocol-oriented-programming

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer